# Mysql possible to returning nested column?

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to ask if mysql queries is possible to select and return nested column in 1 column?

For example:

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Id  |  Name  |                    Address                        |
|      |        |  Address 1  |  Address 2  |  Postcode  |  Country |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1  | Edward |    Value1   |    Value2   | Postcode1  | Country1 |
|      |        |    Value3   |    Value4   | Postcode2  | Country2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2  |   Jin  |    Value5   |    Value6   | Postcode3  | Country3 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then it can be able to get as php associative array:

```html
[
  0 => [
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Edward',
    'address' => [
      0 => [
        'address1' => 'value1',
        'address2' => 'value2',
        'postcode' => 'postcode1',
        'country'  => 'country1',
      ],
      1 => [
        'address1' => 'value3',
        'address2' => 'value4',
        'postcode' => 'postcode2',
        'country'  => 'country2',
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: first normalise the data.

Comment: @Darren I try to retrieve the user that have multiple addresses, and each user may have multiple addresses and I try to do it in 1 mysql query

Comment: @Dagon i had tried to use group_concat() for address but it seems to return a string for all address but multiple column